# Is there a name for a group-like structure under a unary operation?

Tags: group-theory

It seems to me that the set,

$$
S=\{ \sin, \cos, -\sin, -\cos \}
$$

forms something like a cyclic group under differentiation. But I understand groups to be defined to have a binary operation.

Is there a name for a group-like structure under a unary operation?

Comment: Interesting question. An observation is that $\exp$ is an eigenfunction of the differential operator. However, this does not fully answer your question

Comment: See the recent question [Permutation as an algebraic structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712329/permutation-as-an-algebraic-structure).

Comment: To sum up the answers below: the reason this looks "unary" is that the monoid/group/etc. acting on the set is *cyclic* (in other words, generated by one element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me the right context seems to be that the set $M$ consisting of the differentiation operator and its powers is a monoid, and the set you gave is a set with the monoid $M$ acting upon it.

So I would advise you to see [semigroup and monoid actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action).

Comment: To elaborate for the OP: the monoid operation is composition. It might feel a bit more concrete to think of the monoid as $(\mathbb{N},+)$ instead, and the action as $$n\cdot f={d^n\over dx^n}f$$ (for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f\in\{\sin,\cos,-\sin,-\cos\}$), the key relation being that $${d^m\over dx^m}{d^n\over dx^n}f={d^{m+n}\over dx^{m+n}}f.$$

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is a function, and $D$ means "differentiate", and I change your set notation for an ordered 4-tuple (because I'll bet you want order to matter), then what you've got is

$$(D^0 f, D^1 f, D^2 f, D^3 f)$$

where $f$ is $\sin$. A dynamicist would say that you've identified a 4-cycle for the action of $D$ on (differentiable) functions. And as others have noted, there's a **monoid** structure at play here, because $D^n D^m = D^{n+m}$.

Answer (score 2):

The set $S$ is a torsor for the cyclic group of order $4$.

Given a group $G$, a $G$-torsor is a nonempty $G$-set $T$ with the property that
$$\forall x,y \in T \, \exists! g \in G \, gx=y.$$

For
$$G=C_4=\{e,g,g^2,g^3\},$$
one can define an action of $G$ on $S$ by letting $g^nf$ be $f^{(n)}$ (the $n$th derivative of $f$, where the $0$th derivative of a function is simply the function itself) for $n \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and $f \in \{\sin,\cos,-\sin,-\cos\}$.

One can easily check that this action does in fact make $S$ into a $G$-torsor.